Friedman test gives back error: not an unreplicated complete block design. How do I fix this?
Whatever I try, I keep getting the error 'not an unreplicated complete block design' when I try to perform a Friedman test in R.
I have a dataset with the total number of flower visits that I counted on different shrub species, which were then divided into different categories (locations). Since the data did not meet the two-way ANOVA assumptions I turned to the Friedman test. My data frame is as follows:
> diversity_columns
# A tibble: 74 × 3
   Category_ID Species         Total_visits
   <fct>       <fct>                  <dbl>
 1 UN          Common hawthorn           22
 2 UN          Common hawthorn           42
 3 UN          Common hawthorn            3
 4 UN          Common hawthorn           13
 5 UN          Common hawthorn           76
 6 UN          Common hawthorn           95
 7 UN          Common hawthorn           53
 8 RN          Common hawthorn           50
 9 RN          Common hawthorn           18
10 UN          Common hawthorn            6

The labels for the Category_IN are "RA", "RN" and "UN" and for Species "Common hawthorn", "Blackberry" and "Rose"
I tried the following command:
friedman.test(Total_visits ~ Category_ID | Species, data = diversity_columns)

However, I got this error in return:
Error in friedman.test.default(mf[[1L]], mf[[2L]], mf[[3L]]) : 
  not an unreplicated complete block design

I already tried to transform my dataset with the function as.matrix:
as.matrix(diversity_columns)

And I also tried transformed my variables into factors:
Shannon_diversity$Species <- factor(Shannon_diversity$Species)
Shannon_diversity$Category_ID <- factor(Shannon_diversity$Category_ID)


This indicates that your missing at least one of the six cross-categories of Species/Category.ID.
You can see which one(s) are missing by using table:
with(diversity_columns, table(Category_ID, Species))

I can replicate this error using the built-in warpbreaks dataset.
wb <- aggregate(warpbreaks$breaks,
                by = list(w = warpbreaks$wool,
                          t = warpbreaks$tension),
                FUN = mean)
wb


  w t        x
1 A L 44.55556
2 B L 28.22222
3 A M 24.00000
4 B M 28.77778
5 A H 24.55556
6 B H 18.77778

friedman.test(x ~ w | t, data = wb)


    Friedman rank sum test

data:  x and w and t
Friedman chi-squared = 0.33333, df = 1, p-value = 0.5637

This works. Now remove one of the rows from wb:
wb2 <- wb[-2,]
with(wb2, table(w, t))


   t
w   L M H
  A 1 1 1
  B 0 1 1

friedman.test(x ~ w | t, data = wb2)
#Error in friedman.test.default(mf[[1L]], mf[[2L]], mf[[3L]]) : 
  #not an unreplicated complete block design


Thank you for your answer! If I understand this correctly, the error is the result of the fact that the Rose species is only present in category RA (and missing in category UN and RN) and the blackberry species only in the categories UN and RN ()and missing in RA). This does, however, leave me with the question: Which test do I use to compare the number of flower visits? Should I then test each combination manually with a unpaired two-sample Wilcoxon test?

That's a question for StackExchange. :)

Ah, will do! Thank you!
